# A bounded linear functional on a Hilbert space that is a Hahn-Banach extension of one on a subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $M$ be a closed linear subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ and $g\in M*$(all bounded linear functional on $M$). Let $\pi$ be the orthogonal projection of H onto M, then $f=g\circ\pi$ is the only Hahn-Banach extension of g to H.

Can I show this by Riesz's Representation Theorem, g is uniquely determined by an element $v\in M$ and all functional should agree with this element?

Comment: Why do you say that $ f=g\circ \pi$ is the only extension? If $\pi'$ is the projection onto $M^\perp$, couldn't $  f=g\circ \pi+\pi'$ be another extension?

Comment: @guestDiego I think the $f$ in your reply may have a different norm from $g$. For Hahn-Banach extension, the norm should be the same.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, what if I chosse asuitable small coefficient $\epsilon$  so that $  f=g\circ \pi+\epsilon \pi'$?

Comment: @guestDiego Maybe you are right, I'm not sure if this f have the same norm. This is a question from a past exam paper. Maybe that question is wrong.

Comment: Actually you have now almost convinced me that  the statement is true. Actually my "counterexample' in $R^2$, for example, simply does not work! I should think about it more carefully. However, I think that your statement can be true, because the norm of a vector in $M$  has a quadratic correction when you add to it a small perturbation in $M^\perp$. On the other hand $\pi'$ depends linearly form that correction. Maybe you can work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f=g\circ \pi + h\circ(1-\pi)$. Wlog assume $\|f\|=\|g\|=1$. Let $x \in M^\perp$, then $f(x)=h(x)=:h$. Suppose this is $>0$ and let $\|x\|=1$. Let $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $y \in M$, $\|y\|=1$ so that $f(y)≥1-\epsilon$.

Note $\|\alpha x+ \beta y\|^2=|\alpha|^2 \|x\|^2+|\beta|^2\|y\|^2$, so if $(\alpha,\beta) \in S^2$ you have that $\|\alpha x +\beta y\|=1$. On the other hand

$$f(\alpha x+ \beta y)=\alpha h+ \beta(1-\epsilon)$$

Can this be made larger than $1$ for any $h \in (0,1]$? The question is equivalent to considering the case $\epsilon=0$, as $\epsilon$ can be made as small as you like, in any case smaller than $\beta \Delta$ where $\Delta$ would be the gap between the evaluation for $\epsilon=0$ and $1$.

Now write $\alpha=\sqrt{1-\beta^2}$ and find a maximum of

$$h\sqrt{1-\beta^2}+\beta$$

You find that it is taken for $\beta=\frac1{\sqrt{1+h^2}}$, and then plugging this into the expression gives

$$f(\alpha x +\beta y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+h^2}}+h\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+h^2}}=\frac{1+h^2}{\sqrt{1+h^2}}$$

Which is $>1$ for $h>0$.

So any element of the dual that restricts to $g$ on $M$ but is not $g\circ \pi$ must have norm larger than $\|g\|$ and is not a Hahn-Banach extension of $g$.